# touchEnter/touchLeave não funcionam

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Fala galera! Minha duvida é a seguinte: Porque esses eventos touch não estão sendo reconhecidos quando eu entro com o dedo no elemento DOM, ou quando saio dele?

```
var canvasControlsHUD = document.getElementById("canvasControlsHUD");

canvasControlsHUD.addEventListener('touchenter',function(){
        alert('Entered!');
    },false);
    canvasControlsHUD.addEventListener('touchleave',function(){
        alert('Left!');
    },false);
```

Apenas o touchMove funciona.

```
canvasControlsHUD.addEventListener('touchmove',function(){
        alert('Moved!');
    },false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os eventos de touch tem o padrão de nomenclatura um pouco diferente dos de mouse, principalmente devido a diferença de funcionamento entre ambos os tipos de eventos.

Por exemplo, com um mouse, você consegue passar o cursor por cima de um elemento e/ou clicar nele. No touch, você não tem essa opção de `hover`<sup>1</sup>. A única forma de selecionar ou disparar um evento é tocando na tela, logo não faz sentido ter um receptor para este tipo de evento.

Segue abaixo a lista dos valores `touch` existentes, correspondentes aos de `mouse`:

- `mousedown` = `touchstart`
- `mouseup` = `touchend`
- `mousemove` = `touchmove`
- `mouseleave` = `touchleave`

No seu caso, acho que o ideal seria trocar:

```
canvasControlsHUD.addEventListener('touchenter',function(){
    alert('Entered!');
},false);
```

por:

```
canvasControlsHUD.addEventListener('touchstart',function(){
    alert('Started!');
},false);
```

<sup>1. Alguns smartphones (como o Galaxy S4) possuem sensores que disparam evento de `hover` ao se aproximarem da tela. Mas esta funcionalidade ainda não é padrão de mercado.</sup>

Comment: Excelente explicação! Muito obrigado!
Mas, Kazzkiq, eu gostaria de fazer o seguinte: quando a tela fosse tocada, dispara o `touchstart`. Mas caso o dedo seja deslizado para fora desse elemento, o `touchleave` seja disparado. Como fazer entao?

Comment: Em learnprogramming.net84.net/touchevents construi um exemplo dos touchevents, e o `touchleave` nunca é chamado. Porque?